# failed to fetch (axios, nodejs, react)

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fetch-api

My fetch takes too long until it fails

I tried chrome, edge and postman

other fetch requests from pixabay api are working great

I compared the code to other projects I've made and found nothing

I also added a proxy to "package.json" as suggested on some places and it didnt work

posting below parts of my code:

controller:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const getAll = async () =>{
const response = await axios.get('https://pixabay.com/api/?key=25540812-faf2b76d586c1787d2dd02736')
.then(resp=>resp)
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
return response;
}
```

router:

```
import express from "express";
import * as homeController from '../controllers/home.controller.js'

const homeRouter = express.Router();

homeRouter.get('/all', homeController.getAll)

export default homeRouter
```

indexjs:

```
import express from "express"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import homeRouter from './routers/home.router.js'
dotenv.config();

const PORT = 3000 //process.env.PORT
console.log(PORT);


const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(homeRouter)

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{console.log(`server is connected on port ${PORT}`)})
```

fetch:

```
    const getAll = async()=>{
    try {
        const response = await fetch (`http://localhost:3000/all`)
        console.log("hu");
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        else{
            console.log("ok");
        }
        const responseObj = await response.json();
       console.log(responseObj);
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}



 useEffect(()=>{
    getAll();
  },[])
```

Comment: Making `proxy` changes in package.json will not affect the code running in the browser. Have you checked the browser console for errors and messages?

Comment: not your issue, but `.then(resp=>resp)` is completely redundant ... also, if using async/await avoid using `.then` `.catch` - use try/catch with async/await

Comment: @Codebling yep, I saw nothing there

Comment: you're using express, right ... but nowhere are your sending a response - look at [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) to see how your code is wrong

Comment: import axios from 'axios'


export const getAll = async () =>{
const response = await
axios.get('https://pixabay.com/api/?key=25540812-faf2b76d586c1787d2dd02736')
return response
}

Comment: @Jaromanda X I copied exactly what the axios website said to narrow down my mistakes to minimum as I really dont know wat the problem is

Comment: don't read axios documentation to use express properly - axios documentation barely documents axios - see this `app.get('/', (req, res) => {` ... where's you `req` and `res` ??? nowhere, that's where - hint: `export const getAll = async (req, res) =>{`

Comment: @Jaromanda X I cant believe it was it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer by @Jaromanda X for everyone to see:

"see this `app.get('/', (req, res) => {` ... where's you `req` and `res` ??? nowhere, that's where - hint: `export const getAll = async (req, res) =>{`"

Apparently EVERY controller made with express needs to send a response back (in the form of res.send)

Should be obvious but somehow I missed it

Thanks everyone!